# Scroll to bottom of page when scroll down and to top when scroll up smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I have a webpage with 2 stacked divs with 100vh height each. I have 2 objectives:

1. The browser has to scroll all the way down to the bottom of the second div when the user scrolls down. Conversely scroll up to the top of the first div when the user scrolls up. Essentially,  I want to allow only for two scroll positions (top and bottom of the document).
2. I want the scrolling to be animated so it feels smooth when moving up/down.

**Markup here**

```
   <div class='jumbotron' style='height:100vh;'></div>
   <div class='content' style='height:100vh;'></div>
```

My first attempt achieves the first objective but not the second with the following code.

```
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (st > lastScrollTop){
        $(window).scrollTop(1000);
     }
     else {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
  });
```

I've tried the following code but it has 2 problems. Firstly, the scroll down animation kicks in very slowly so it gets confusing for the user. Secondly, for some reason once the browser scrolls to the bottom of the page it gets stuck there and never goes back up.

```
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (st > lastScrollTop){
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#displayed-text").offset().top
        }, 2000);
     }
     else {
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".jumbotron").offset().top
        }, 2000);
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
  });
```

Can you guide me to find a better way to achieve these 2 objectives successfully?

Comment: I guess it's a typo in else case `scrollTop: $(".jumbotron")` shouldn't it be `scrollTop: $(".jumbotron").offset().top`?

Comment: Thanks, indeed I missed adding .offset().top
However, the problem persists the scroll position gets stuck in the bottom of the second div when I try to scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

scrollTop gets a number and scroll to that number on the page, in the second animation you give the scroolTop a jquery object = `$(".jumbotron")`, you should do the same as you did above with offset().top which return a number, the position of the top of the given div.
so `$(".jumbotron").offset().top`.

Also you set the animation to 2 seconds, meaning that the animation you want (to move from top to bottom and bottom to top) will take 2 seconds to finish, if you want it to be faster you need to play with the second argument you pass to .animate(), in milliseconds, 1000 = 1 second.

Updated code:

```
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var animationTime = 2000; //play with that number to get the right speed you want
  $(window).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (st > lastScrollTop){
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#displayed-text").offset().top
        }, animationTime);
     }
     else {
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".jumbotron").offset().top
        }, animationTime);
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed I missed adding .offset().top
However, the problem persists the scroll position gets stuck in the bottom of the second div when I try to scroll up.
Also, re the animation timing it's not the time that takes for the animation to finish but the delay between the time the animation is triggered (a scroll event is detected) and the start of the animation.

Comment: well then the values you are getting are wrong, console.log all the values (st, lastScrollTop, $(".jumbotron").offset().top) to check what are the values you get, i guess you will find that 1 value is not what you expected.